# Using pybind11 within C++ in JUCE Framework

Tags: python, c++, embed, pybind11, juce

I'm trying to read a string list output from a Python script, in order to pass it to a JUCE MainComponent (written in C++).

The code is the following (which is a starting one, just to test the pybind library):

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
namespace py = pybind11;

MainComponent::MainComponent()
{
    auto math = py::module::import("math");
    auto resultobj = math.attr("sqrt")(2);
    double result = resultobj.cast<double>();
}
```

However, I always encounter the following error:

```
_PyRuntime.gc.**generation0** was nullptr.
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to first initialize the Python interpreter, like this:

```cpp
MainComponent::MainComponent()
{
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};

    auto math = py::module::import("math");
    auto resultobj = math.attr("sqrt")(2);
    double result = resultobj.cast<double>();
}
```

You also have to link with the needed python libraries. In CMake, this means adding

```
target_link_libraries(your_target PRIVATE pybind11::embed)
```

to your CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: I have already added `py::scoped_interpreter guard{};` but the error is still present.

Comment: Moreover, the JUCE framework did not generate the CMakeLists.txt file. Maybe I wasn't able to retrive this file... do you know where it is located inside a JUCE project folder?

Comment: I'm not sure how JUCE framework's build system works, but it seems to have CMake support (https://forum.juce.com/t/native-built-in-cmake-support-in-juce/38700)